# Running webpack throws 'Callback was already called' error

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I just started learning webpack to manage dependencies in my project. I am trying to use it to build bundles for my typescript and javascript files. For the typescript files, I am using the `ts-loader` plugin for handling it. For CSS, I am using the `mini-css-extract` and an `optimize-css-assets` plugin. When I try to run webpack, I get the following error and I am not able to figure out what might be causing this error.

```
user@system spl % npm run build

> spl@1.0.0 build /Users/user/Downloads/spl
> webpack --config webpack.config.js

/Users/user/Downloads/spl/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16
    throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
    ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at throwError (/Users/user/Downloads/spl/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:16:11)
    at /Users/user/Downloads/spl/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! spl@1.0.0 build: `webpack --config webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the spl@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2020-05-14T14_23_32_985Z-debug.log
```

The following is my webpack.config file that I am using to build my dist files.

```
const path = require('path');

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: "./static/js/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.[contentHash].js",  // File name with hash, based on content
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
            new TerserPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: "./static/index.html",
                minify: {
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeComments: true
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[contentHash].css"
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [ "html-loader" ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.[tj]s$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /(node_modules|tests)/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            static: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
        },
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: @JG_GJ I was linking the styles sheet in the index.html. We need to instead import it in JS as shown in the fanswer below.

Comment: I have done the same by removing all the css link from the index and importing them into the js, but I still have the problem :( using webpack 4.44

Comment: Share the index.html file so that we can try to see what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I realized that I was importing CSS file from my `index.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
```

although the CSS file should have been imported from entry file (`index.js`) using `import`:

```
import '../css/main.css';
```

so I deleted the line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">` and solved the problem.
You can see your HTML file and check if there are any assets imported from your HTML file. I hope it helped.

Comment: What if it is necessary to import assets in HTML to preload for example? what to do in this case?

Comment: The same thing happens to me, I have done this but it does not work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** Upgrading webpack to a newer version solved it for me.

I went into `node_modules/neo-async/async.js` and modified the `onlyOnce` so that it gives a bit more descriptive stack trace like this:

```
  /**
   * @private
   * @param {Function} func
   */
  function onlyOnce(func) {
    const defined = new Error('onlyOnce first used here')
    return function(err, res) {
      var fn = func;
      func = () => {
        console.error(defined);
        throwError();
      };
      fn(err, res);
    };
  }
```

The stack trace points into webpack’s internal code, which, when I upgraded to the latest version, solves this issue.

Comment: Thai can you remember what webpack versions you upgraded from/to that fixed this?

Comment: @TomMcIntyre [It was from 4.20.2 to 4.46.0.](https://github.com/bemusic/bemuse/commit/f15619bae9620d5e2a6ee144acc7c14aea5c90b7)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and was able to determine that the cause was circular dependencies in Typescript, not outdated dependencies as suggested by other answers here. This error appeared when I refactored code from `import MyClass from "folder/file"` into `import { MyClass } from "folder"`.

I only considered this possibility after reading this post about [differences in semantics between `export default`](https://jakearchibald.com/2021/export-default-thing-vs-thing-as-default/) and other types of exports.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was related to a recent downgrade someone had made to mini-css-extract-plugin.  We are using pnpm, so this answer is specific to that.  I had to delete the `pnpm-lock.yaml` file in the module I was trying to run out of spring boot dashboard in VSCode.  This file is generated if it is missing, but for us anyway, it was committed to the repo. If that doesn't work for you, you might also consider deleting the npm-cache and `.pnpm-store` dirs.  The locations of those files are configured in the `.npmrc` file in your user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue came after upgrading css-loader. Downgrading it back to the original version did the trick for me

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 7151c509..b0eba48b 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -111,7 +111,7 @@
     "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
-    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
+    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
```