# NPM behaves differently when project is in another folder

Tags: node.js, powershell, vue.js, asp.net-core, npm

I'm creating a Vue Frontend with a .Net Core 3.1 Backend, but
when I try the command nmp run build in the project it exits with Code 1.

The weird part is:
If I take the frontend app and put it in another parent folder it compiles successfully.
It also works if I try it with PowerShell Version 7.

Error Message:

```
C:\Users\first.last\source\repos\Company.Project\Company.ProjectNew\project-frontend\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16
    throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
    ^

Error: Callback was already called.
    at throwError (C:\Users\first.last\source\repos\Company.Project\Company.ProjectNew\project-frontend\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16:11)
    at C:\Users\first.last\source\repos\Company.Project\Company.ProjectNew\project-frontend\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! testapp@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the testapp@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\first.last\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-16T13_40_43_756Z-debug.log
```

The folder Structure:

```
Company.Project
   Company.ProjectNew <-- This is the .net Web App
      project-frontend <-- This is the vue porject
Company.Project.sln
```

Please help! I'M LOSING MY MIND!!

Comment: Please describe the folder structure of your project(s) in more detail, and post the full error message

Comment: Have you looked into [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799995/running-webpack-throws-callback-was-already-called-error)?

Comment: Yeah, already looked at that, but no look. I also tried it with a completly blank vue project. Still got the same error.

Comment: Does the actual name of your `project-frontend` folder contain uppercase characters? If yes, try renaming it `Project-Frontend` -> `project-frontend` (as per [this issue](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-cli-service-build-failed-with-async-js-callback-called-multiple-times/118988))

Comment: I also tried that before. Didn't work either.

Comment: Is your code selecting the right node version? Do you have an .nvmrc? Is `nvm use` part of the build script?

Comment: Also no, I have only one Node version installed. v14.18.0.